# Resources for batteries?

Tags: batteries

I was wondering if someone could recommend a textbook or some online resource on batteries- working with lifepo4 for the first time and I was wondering what all I should be worried about and what all I need to be testing.

Tried to find stuff online but it was difficult to find anything that went into depth.

Thanks

Comment: Try using the search term 'batteries' on the web. You will find more info than you can read in a year.

Comment: The keyword ***primer*** on Google helps find some short intros to any technology.  For 'lifepo4 battery primer' you get a ton of info. LIKE this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.mit.edu/2.009/www/resources/mediaAndArticles/batteriesPrimer.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjFwcbUverMAhUHUVIKHZqhDmMQFghPMA0&usg=AFQjCNFtNuGITuhorRF667QrQ1SSj_EKQQ&sig2=OSAhvo6CtLUiBbttEf4iQQ

Comment: Oh, you want in depth articles? Try reading the references used in the Wikipedia article for LFP batteries. Most are books exclusively about LFP batteries.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - read the bit about shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from here:

- [How to charge Lithium Iron Phosphate Rechargeable Lithium Ion Batteries](http://www.powerstream.com/LLLF.htm)
- Battery university [cell types](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/types_of_lithium_ion) and [anything related](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/) to lithium batteries.

or if you are patient and open to learn a lot [read ALL this document](http://www.artechhouse.com/static/sample/barsukov-491_ch04.pdf). It's the best resource I found and it would have saved me a lot of time if I understood this stuff from the beginning.